# Trigger a circuit with square wave

Tags: switches

I have a circuit that develops an 800Hz square wave of 5 volts and about 200mA (it's a buzzer oscillator) when energized, I want to detect this square wave and turn on another 5v circuit with a separate power source (an audio playback IC) when the square wave is present, and then turn it off when the square wave is absent. I could do this with an arduino and interrupts, but is there a way to do it in analog? I'm looking for the lowest component count (cost) and complexity possible... if I just run the 800hz signal through a capacitor can I use the smoothed output to switch a transistor? I really just need to get a "hi" output while the square wave is present, and "low" when absent. I can trigger the target device either by switching its power or using a ttl signal.

This seems like it should be a very basic question, but I'm very much a novice...

Comment: Voltage of the signal? Source impedance (or, alternatively, what ***exactly*** is developing your square wave?) What voltage do you want at the output for "on" and what for "off?" How many cycles are permitted to figure out that it is off or on?

Comment: What is the amplitude of the square wave?  What exactly is producing this square wave?  What is the circuit putting out when it is not putting out the square wave?  How frequency selective does it need to be, e.g. does it need to not respond to a < 799Hz wave and a > 801 Hz wave?  There is a lot of fuzziness in your question.  You need to provide a lot more detail in order for someone to be able to reasonably answer the question.

Comment: added some more detail. I don't need selectivity, in fact i'm not sure exactly how stable my 800Hz square wave is, so wide response range is desirable. The circuit has no voltage/signal when not outputting the square wave. The signal is generated internally in a custom IC and I cannot isolate the signal that turns the oscillator on and off, jut the output itself.

Comment: @JawzX What you need is basically a *Retriggerable Monostable Multivibrator*. There are 555/7555 circuits available on the web and there's also the 74121/74123 ICs (though I think those are getting harder to get these days?) Glen's concept is essentially that, passing alternating half-cycle pulses to Q1 and using R1+C1 to set a hold period of sorts. If it causes trouble for some reason, one added discrete active can make it a precision tool and a second added discrete active provides the load switch capable of high load currents and precise on/off switching. No ICs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do this. You intend to do a logical function (turn on - turn off) which suggests a comparator. First circuit uses a transistor. The square wave must be larger than 0.6V peak-to-peak. If it is, the transistor turns on - its collector current pulls R1 down near zero-volts. Capacitor C1 is pulled down as well, but starts to charge back to the supply voltage during the last half of the 800 Hz. square wave. \$ R1 * C1 \$ time constant should be significantly longer than the 800 Hz. period.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6SN2z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
You could use a proper comparator chip to do a similar function.
When the square-wave amplitude exceeds the threshold voltage set by R2, its output goes low, otherwise output is high. The output *stays low* because of the RC time constant of R1 & C1 at its output. The time constant should be longer than the 800 Hz. period (1.25 milliseconds).
At the input, a diode clamp prevents a large amplitude square wave from going too far negative. R3 establishes a zero-volt reference:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkqesp.png)</sup>

A disadvantage of these circuits is that *any frequency* (not *just* 800 Hz) will cause the output to go low. And a low frequency will output multiple pulses - use this circuit if 800 Hz. (or higher frequency) is expected.

If you want to detect **only 800 Hz.**, then a more complex circuit is required. A LM567 can provide a frequency-selective output indicator.
A 4046 phase-locked-loop can perform a similar function: [CMOS Phase-Locked-Loop Applications](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/scha003b/scha003b.pdf)

Comment: thanks! #1 is along the lines of what i was hoping for, I've got everything to build that circuit in my junk box and can knock it together in a couple minutes. I think it should do what I want.